# Share bookmarks between Firefox on Mac OS X and Firefox on Windows 7 Boot Camp

Tags: windows, mac, firefox, bookmarks

How do I share bookmarks between Firefox on Mac OS X and Firefox on Windows 7 Boot Camp?

Answer (score 0):

With the [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [delicious.com](http://www.delicious.com), which works in multiple browsers and multiple OS's.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.